# Why is Akamai cache-control max-age decreasing value?

Tags: performance, cache-control, akamai

I am using Akamai and the `cache-control` headers `max-age` value is decreasing on each subsequent request when using [honor origin cache control + expires](https://developer.akamai.com/blog/2017/03/28/what-you-need-know-about-caching-part-1). On other CDNs I don't experience the same behaviour.

On the app I have `Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public` and the max-age value in the response headers seems to be calculated as the time Akamai fetched the asset from the server minus the max-age specified in the app.

Why is this happening? How can I have Akamai respond with `max-age=2592000, public`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can easily configure this via "Downstream cacheability"
> behaviour: » "Pass cacheability headers from origin" » This tunnels
> the Cache-Control and/or Expires header settings from the origin to
> the downstream.

[image: Pass cacheability headers from origin]

> Alternatively, for resources with TTL defined at the Edge you can set
> this to "Full edge TTL (max-age)".

[image: Full edge TTL]

Thanks to @TimVereeke.